# Multiplying negative and positive sound values separately

Tags: java, arrays, javasound

I need to create a method to multiply all of the positive values in a sound array by a certain number, and then multiply all of the negative values by a different number. So far, I have only been able to multiply ALL of the values in an array by a certain number. Here is my code for it below...

```
public void soundNormalized() // max you can divide by is 0.81231 // max value can be seen at index 2497
 {
   SoundSample[] sampleArray = this.getSamples();
   SoundSample sample = null;
   int value = 0;
   double factor = 0.8123159884711935;

   // loop through the samples in the array
   for (int i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++)
   {
     sample = sampleArray[i];
     value = sample.getValue();
     sample.setValue((int) (value / factor));
   }
 }
```

This works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to multiply negative and positive numbers separately for the life of me.

Comment: Ok so you'll essentially need 3 arrays. One that has all the numbers, the other that collects positive numbers, and another that collects negative numbers...

Comment: How would I initialize the array so that it only collects negative or positive numbers?

Comment: `if (value < 0)`? What's the problem?

Comment: Look at Radlodef's comment...

Comment: If you don't know how to use an `if` statement, it seems, umm, trivial. Like you should be reading [basic language tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), not asking StackOverflow about it. If there is some other problem, please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: what did you put in the if block?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank you for your help. I should have thought of using an if statement, I feel really stupid now